# Why is the End-of-File character not being interpreted correctly?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 77

int getline(char[], int);

main() {
    char in_line[MAXLENGTH];
    int count, in_line_length;

    in_line_length = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < MAXLENGTH; ++count)
        in_line[count] = 0;
    in_line_length = getline(in_line, MAXLENGTH);
    printf("%s", in_line);
}

int getline(char line[], int max_length) {
    int count, character;

    character = 0;

    for (count = 0; count < (max_length -2) && (character = getchar()) != EOF && character != '\n'; count++) {
        line[count] = character;
    }
    if (character = '\n') {
        line[count++] = '\n';
    }
    line[count] = '\0';
    return count;
}
```

I'm having a peculiar issue with the above code. As a little background, I'm compiling the above C code with the Tiny C Compiler (TCC) and running the executable in a Windows XP command prompt (`cmd.exe`).

The problem that appears to be occuring has to do with the `EOF` character. When running, if I issue the `EOF` character (`CTRL+Z`) and then hit return, the loop seems to exit correctly, but then `character` is populated with a newline character (`\n`).

So, something like this (as input):

```
test^Ztesttwo
```

Would output:

```
test\n
```

Due to the fact that the `if statement` following the `for loop` is always executed. What I'm wondering, is why the loop successfully exits upon recognition of the `EOF` character if it continues to grab another character from the stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
if (character = '\n') {
```

it is an assigment instead of a test operator:

```
if (character == '\n') {
```

You can prevent erros like this by putting the constant left, that way you will get a compiler error if you make a mistake.

```
if ('\n' = character) {
//       ^ wont compile
```